# Unexpected Error Message in RStudio; while using 'twitterR' Package

Tags: r

I'd install an R package `twitterR` in my RStudio for accessing Twitter data for a particular handle. But whenever I do try to access the Twitter data it's showing me an unexpected message:

```
In doRppAPICall(“search/tweets”, n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit, :
100 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

Any thoughts on that?

I tried different parameters, handles and functionalities but still getting the same issue.

Here's my code for the particular functionality--

```
my_tweets <- searchTwitter('@jabhij', geocode='20.593684, 78.96288, 2000km', n = 100)
my_tweets_df <- do.call("rbind", laaply(my_tweets, as.data.frame))
View(my_tweets_df)
```

Any thoughts on that will be very helpful.
Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the whitespace in the parameter for `geocode`.

It should be:

```
my_tweets <- searchTwitter('@jabhij', geocode="20.593684,78.96288,2000km")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Your parameters are in the wrong order, place n before geocode. You must also avoid any whitespace within the geocode.